Why do the MBR partition entry and partition filesystem disagree on the number of sectors?
I've got an SD card used for booting a Beaglebone Black. I was having problems booting from the card, or any card for that matter that I created, and I finally tracked down the problem to a disagreement in the number of sectors in the boot partition.
What I mean is, dumping the MBR with dd and checking the first partition entry, the Number of sectors in partition gives 0x40000. This is also what e.g. GParted reports. Then, dumping the FAT16 boot partition, the Large number of sectors is only 0x3fff8. This is a difference of 8, which happens to also be the number of hidden sectors reported by the partition (despite being at offset 2048). But why? The boot ROM seems to be throwing its error because the two numbers don't agree, and I didn't think hidden sectors were even considered in the vast majority of cases, let alone when determining the number of sectors. What gives?

"the MBR partition entry and partition itself disagree" – Not "partition itself", but the filesystem within. Windows did a lot to make people believe partitions and filesystems (and even disks) are the same concept, while there are certainly not. The partition entry is what defines the partition, there is nothing else. The "partition itself" is just a range of sectors and it has no structure. You can create some structure within, e.g. a filesystem; but then the elements of the structure (and whether or not they agree with whatever) conceptually belong to the structure, not to the partition.

@KamilMaciorowski thanks for that insight, updated the wording in the title

The data structures in filesystems do not necessarily support all possible values of sizes.  Frequently, only a multiple of certain sizes are supported.   So when the filesystem is created on a partition, the partition size is rounded down to the closest size the filesystem supports.
As long as the filesystem size isn't larger than the partition, this is not a problem and should not prevent booting.  (If the filesystem is larger than the partition, then some data will be truncated off the end and the filesystem would be corrupt.)
Likely something else is preventing booting, but since you didn't include any actual errors in your question, this can't be addressed.
In comments, you mention that the -a option allowed you to make a filesystem that matched size exactly.  Without this option, the default is to align filesystem data structures to the "cluster size".  The cluster size (-s) is the number of blocks per cluster, probably with a calculated default based on disk size.
A typical SD card uses a 2k block, but advertises a 512 byte block.  One would hope the filesystem cluster size would be a multiple of this (multiple of -s4 maybe).  Misalignment or a different cluster size may force the sdcard to split writes across physical block boundaries, which might have devastating performance consequences (as mentioned in the man page).
However, if your partition boundary ls already misaligned to this block boundary, the -a option may accidentally allow the filesystem to realign back to it, especially if the partition ends at the end of the disk and there's some left over blocks without -a.

Thanks for answering. re: the errors, the problem is more involved than I can get into here, but I'm stepping instructions in the boot ROM and reverse engineered the SD card booting functions, and if I skip the compare instruction comparing the 0x40000 to 0x3FFF8, the boot procedure continues as expected. It's a bit of an XY problem here, I admit, but sure that if the two numbers match, boot continues normally.

You might be able to shrink the partition size to match the filesystem size, but watch for fence post errors.  If this is actually the problem, it is a bug in the boot rom.

Fixed it! Reviewing the mkfs commands for building the FAT16 filesystem, I noticed that another reference uses the -a flag, which disables alignment. This was the key. Adding that flag and rebuilding, the sector counts agree (0x40000) and the system boots. I guess the boot ROM doesn't support that sort of alignment? Weird. Can you give some insight into the alignment and how it affects the listed number of sectors? Then I'll accept the answer.
